# Best handling of constructor with default values

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I have class of multiple properties all with default values. The properties are not optional, they are required but have default values. For example:

```
String fillColor = "White";
String borderColor = "Blue";
int size = 10;
```

Is it bad practice to have a single constructor and to pass in null values when default values are desired?

```
Object myObject = new Object(null, null, 15);
```

Alternatively, I was thinking of possibly implementing a builder.

Answer (score 2):

It's a judgment call.

Imagine someone reading the code who doesn't know your class very well. Will they be able to understand what the two `null`s mean? They'll probably have to look up the constructor and see what those parameters are. Even familiar users might have a hard time remembering whether the fill or the border color comes first.

These are good arguments for having more constructors, or even going with a builder class. Additional constructors allow the unused arguments to be omitted entirely.

```
Object(int size);
Object(String fillColor, String borderColor);
Object(String fillColor, String borderColor, int size);
```

The downside is that you have to have different constructors for every combination of omitted arguments. It can get unwieldy if there are lots of combinations. In the worst case for *n* arguments you might have to provide 2<sup>*n*</sup> constructors.

It also doesn't help if the user wants to set one color but not the other.

```
Object(String fillColor);     // ambiguous overloads
Object(String borderColor);
```

A builder provides maximum flexibility. Settings are set independently from each other, avoiding the exponential blowup described earlier. Settings with the same type are no longer ambiguous. Having both fill color and border color be strings is not a problem:

```
class ObjectBuilder {
    ObjectBuilder fillColor(String fillColor);
    ObjectBuilder borderColor(String borderColor);
    Objectbuilder size(int size);
    Object build();
}
```

The tradeoff is increased code complexity. A builder class is a fair amount of work to create. It also makes construction a lot more verbose, which could be a positive *or* a negative. Use your best judgment.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it bad practice to have a single constructor and to pass in null values when default values are desired?

Yes. You are assuming that people reading the code will know that "null means default", as opposed to e.g. them actually wanting the values to be null.

Add an overload that you can call without the meaningless cruft of the literal nulls:

```
Object myObject = new Object(15);
```

which invokes the other constructor:

```
Object(int size) {
  this("White", "Blue", size);
}
```

or a static factory method (which has the "named constructor" advantage mentioned in *Effective Java* Item 1, allowing the meaning of the int parameter to be self-documented):

```
static Object createWithSize(int size) {
  return new Object ("White", "Blue", size);
}
```

Comment: If the "default values" do not depend on which constructor is used, or one of the provided values, then I'd initialize the member variables as opposed to requiring a `this(...)` call.  For your example, just `this.size = size`. The defaults should be in one single location, not spread out over other constructor `this()` calls.

Comment: @JimGarrison to each his own. I am used to writing classes where there is "one true constructor", and all the others are simply convenience overloads which call `this(...)`.

Comment: In this case, say you had 5 different constructors all calling the "1 true constructor", then you'd have to keep track of defaults in all 5 `this()` calls. When a default changes, do you want to be looking for it in 5 places?

Comment: @JimGarrison also, why is `this.foo = "defaultFoo"; this.bar = "defaultBar";` better at not scattering defaults than `this("defaultFoo", "defaultBar");`? You've still got the defaults in that ctor. Perhaps I've misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: @JimGarrison define the default in a static member?

Comment: No, I did not mean that.  I meant initialize the defaults where the member is declared, not in the constructor.

Comment: If you mean `this(size); this.foo = "defaultFoo";`, that precludes making `foo` final. Also precluded by defining the default on the field initializer.